# How to assign a group as Users on an endpoint in VSTS via the API?

Tags: rest, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to tidy up VSTS and ensure that the AzureRM endpoints are consistent across our 40+ projects. I've written a Powershell script to call the rest API and ensure that the same endpoints are available for all projects. This works fine.

One thing I want to do though is grant the Contributors group for each project User rights on the non-prod endpoints. This *doesn't* seem to work and the official documentation ([create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/serviceendpoint/endpoints/create?view=vsts-rest-4.1) or [update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/serviceendpoint/endpoints/update%20service%20endpoint?view=vsts-rest-4.1)) doesn't provide any real guidance on it.

I can get the group and pass this as being the "readersGroup" in the JSON Body of the call and this is then echoed in the response, implying it worked, but this doesn't appear to change anything on the endpoint itself.

Has anyone done this before who can give me some guidance as to where I'm going wrong?

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [ValidateSet("Production","NonProduction","RandD")][string]$Environment,
    [string]$SubscriptionName,
    [string]$SubscriptionDisplayName = $SubscriptionName,
    [string]$SubscriptionId,
    [string]$TenantId,
    [string]$ClientId,
    [string]$ClientKey,
    [string]$Token  #Required Scopes: Graph (read), Project and team (read), Service Endpoints (read, query and manage)
)

#Set up Endpoint data
$EndpointDisplayName = "$Environment ($SubscriptionDisplayName)"
$EndpointConfiguration = @"
{
    "data": {
        "SubscriptionId": "$SubscriptionId",
        "SubscriptionName": "$SubscriptionName",
        "creationMode" : "Manual"
    },
    "name": "$EndpointDisplayName",
    "type": "azurerm",
    "url" : "https://management.azure.com/",
    "authorization": {
        "parameters": {
            "serviceprincipalid" : "$ClientId",
            "serviceprincipalkey" : "$ClientKey",
            "tenantid" : "$TenantId"
        },
        "scheme": "ServicePrincipal"
    }
}
"@

#Set up API data
$Authentication = [Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$Token")
$Authentication = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($Authentication)
$Headers = @{
    'Authorization' = "Basic $Authentication"
    'Content-Type' = "application/json"
}
$BaseURI = "https://contoso.visualstudio.com"
$APIVersion = "?api-version=4.1-preview.1"

#get all vsts projects
$ListProjectsURI = "$BaseURI/DefaultCollection/_apis/projects$APIVersion"
$ProjectList = (Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $ListProjectsURI -Headers $Headers).value

#Get VSTS Contributor groups for "user" role assignment
$ListGroupsURI = "https://Contoso.vssps.visualstudio.com/_apis/graph/groups$APIVersion" 
$GroupsList = (Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $ListGroupsURI -Headers $Headers).value
$AllContributorsGroups = $GroupsList | Where-Object -Property principalName -like "*\Contributors"

foreach($Project in $ProjectList)
{
    $ProjectName = $Project.name
    $ProjectId = $Project.id
    #get all AzureRM SP endpoints
    $ListEndpointsURI = "$BaseURI/$ProjectId/_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints$APIVersion&type=azurerm&authschemes=ServicePrincipal"
    $EndpointList = (Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $ListEndpointsURI -Headers $Headers).value
    $Exists = $false

    #set up the endpoint settings for this project
    if($Environment -eq "Production")
    {
        $EndpointJSON = $EndpointConfiguration
    }
    else #grant devs access to use non-prod/R&D endpoints
    {
        Write-Host "Setting [$ProjectName]\Contributors as Users on $EndpointDisplayName in $ProjectName"
        $ReadersGroup = ($AllContributorsGroups | Where-Object -Property principalName -eq "[$ProjectName]\Contributors") | ConvertTo-Json
        $ReadersConfiguration = @"
    ,"readersGroup" : $ReadersGroup
}
"@
        $EndpointJSON = $EndpointConfiguration.TrimEnd('}') + $ReadersConfiguration #Append the readers role for this project to the base configuration
    }

    #Look for existing matching endpoints
    foreach($Endpoint in $EndpointList)
    {
        $EndpointName = $Endpoint.name
        $EndpointId = $Endpoint.id

        #check if it uses the subscription Id we're updating,
        if($Endpoint.data.subscriptionId -eq $SubscriptionId)
        {
            #if so, update it
            Write-Host "Updating endpoint `"$EndpointName`" in Project `"$ProjectName`" (Endpoint ID: $EndpointId)"
            $UpdateEndpointURI = "$BaseURI/$ProjectId/_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints/$EndpointId$APIVersion"
            Invoke-RestMethod -Method PUT -Uri $UpdateEndpointURI -Headers $Headers -Body $EndpointJSON
            $Exists = $true
        }
    }
    #if no existing endpoints match, create one
    if(!$Exists)
    {
        Write-Output "No endpoint found for $SubscriptionName in `"$ProjectName`". Creating endpoint `"$EndpointDisplayName`"."
        $CreateEndpointURI = "$BaseURI/$ProjectId/_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints$APIVersion"
        Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $CreateEndpointURI -Headers $Headers -Body $EndpointJSON
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this API instead:

Put

`https://{account}.visualstudio.com/_apis/securityroles/scopes/distributedtask.serviceendpointrole/roleassignments/resources/{project id}_{endpoint id}?api-version=5.0-preview.1`

Body (application/json)

```
[{"roleName":"User","userId":"{group or user id (originId)"}]
```